# Resize My TableView Background

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have changed my TableView background by using this code

```
tableView.backgroundView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "wall"))
```

I would like to resize the background programmatically

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried changing the backgroundView's frame?

```
var tableView = UITableView()
tableView.backgroundView?.frame = CGRect(x: yourX, y: yourY, width: yourWidth, height: yourHeight)
```

**EDIT**

For altering the content mode for the image, you can do something like this:

```
var imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "image"))
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
```

or

```
imageView.contentMode = .scaleToFill
```

or

```
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
```

You can see which one works best for you. There are also a few more, so you can choose the best one.

Comment: I tried your code but the result wasnt good. I think I need to change the content mode for the picture for instance, scale to fit and aspect fit. Is there any way to do that programmatically ? .... Thanks a lot

Comment: Thanks you so much

Comment: If I've helped you with the correct answer, please don't forget to mark it as the correct answer so that future users can find the right help as quickly as possible. Thanks!

Comment: Setting the frame doesn't work. Apple docs say "the table view automatically resizes the background view to match its own bounds"